# Proving that a limit doesnt exist even if it exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

When I was trying to find a path that would prove that some limit doesn't exists, I was simply equaling the equation to a number and finding some expression. I will use some trivial limit, that can be easily be proven to exist by Definition or by Squeeze Theorem, to show the case.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$
Since this fraction is limited
$$0\le\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le1$$
I can multiply both sides by $y$
$$0\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y\le\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\le\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y$$
Which only solution is
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=0$$
So we know the limit exists and it is equal to 0.
$$ $$
But if I take this curve (that I found simply equaling the limit to 1)
$$x = \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{y-1}}$$
I think it's okay because when $y\to0, x\to 0$.So the limit will be:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{y^3}{y-1}}{\frac{y^2}{y-1}+y^2}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\frac{y^3}{y-1}}{\frac{y^3}{y-1}}=1$$
So I found a path that proves the limit doesn't exist. But we know it exists, so must be something wrong.
Did I missed something ? Where is the mistake ? I feel that there is something wrong in the domain of the curve, but since the domain is $y\gt 1$ or $y = 0$ I can't prove that with some formality.

Comment: You should have multiplied both sides by $|y|$ instead, but this is not a real issue because again you'll get a $0$ limit. The problem is that the path you mentioned is not defined for $y < 1$.

Comment: You multiplied both sides by 0. This eliminated any values you wouldve had. Think x = y vs 0 = 0. 0 = 0 is the entire space whereas x = y is a subset with the possibility of being the empty set.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck where did multiplication by $0$ both sides take place?

Comment: Indeed you found two paths (I suspect) which have different limiting values, so the limit doesn't exist.   The stuff about multiplying by $y$ and letting $y$ go to zero doesn't make sense for the reason @TheGreatDuck points out.

Comment: @AhmedHussein:  The reasoning about using Squeeze Lemma involves assuming the limit of $x^2 y/(x^2+y^2)$ exists.  The argument shows (by multiplying the bounded expression $x^2/(x^2+y^2)$ by $y$) that *if* the limit existed, then it would be zero.  But this is not a proof that the limit does exist.

Comment: @hardmath but $0 \le \frac{x^2 |y|}{x^2 + y^2} \le |y|$ does show that the limit exists and that it is equal to zero.

Comment: So, I wasnt really focusing on the proof of existence, since this limit is quite popular. I know the delta and epsilons is the best way, but the thing was with showing the path I choose and what was wrong with it.

Comment: I was thinking that having y go to zero made an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I take this curve (that I found simply equaling the limit to 1)
>   $$x = \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{y-1}}$$

But $\varphi(y)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{y-1}},y\right)$ is *not* a valid path to $(0,0)$, Namely, it is only defined for $y>1$, so you cannot follow $\varphi(y)$ while having $y\to 0$.

Comment: I cant see why is not a valid path. The domain of $f(y) = \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{y-1}}$ is $y\gt 1$ or $y=0$, no ? Can you explain further ?

Comment: To have a valid path, you need it to be defined when $y\to 0$, i.e. when $y$ gets closer and closer to $0$ (whether it is defined for $y=0$ is irrelevant, but it matters it is defined in a neighborhood of $0$ of the form $(0,\varepsilon)$). This is not: for instance, what is $\varphi(0.1)$?

Comment: In other terms, you need a *continuous path to $0$.*

Comment: hm, Now I see why,Without having a continuous path to (0,0) I cant say that I am approaching the (0,0) and using it as a valid path, Which is quite obvious. Even probably there is some formality on this, I think I got it. Really thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: You're welcome! (If that any consolation, this is a rather sneaky mistake).

Comment: @JhonattanFarah Incidentally, if you feel this has fully resolved your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the $\checkmark$ symbol on the left.